# which jQuery code snippet to get url from event object is better w.r.t platform independence

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

just now I am working on a 300 lines long jQuery-dependent javascript file not written by me. It's been a while since I did JS programming.

Well, I had to extract the url from an event object passed into a function.

In one place I for myself came up with this code :

```
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var url = $target.get().toString();
```

However, in another function I found this fragment written by someone else

```
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget),
  url = $target.attr('href');
```

Which fragment is better, or safer w.r.t platform independence cross-browser usability? Are they equivalent?

I realize that the second relies on JS-internal methods (thus might be faster), and not on jquery methods, but maybe it is *less* platform independent for this very reason?

Comment: I don't see any JS-internal methods in the second block of code? (`.attr()` is a jQuery method).

Comment: Spudley, you're right. I have confused it with the .href attribute. I'll leave the remark